# I can't click the button

Tags: python, selenium

I am not able to click the button on this webpage.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\name\Downloads\q\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.plusportals.com/GuardianAngels")

login_button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btn btn-primary pull-right")
login_button.submit()
```

Comment: _I am not able to ..._ What happens when you try?  Do you get an error?  Saying "I can't" is not very helpful.

Comment: You are probably getting an error about compound class names. The issue is that you are using `find_elements_by_class_name()` and then passing in 3 different class names. You need to either choose one class name or convert it into a CSS selector, ".btn.btn-primary.pull-right".

Answer (score 0):

Replacing line 5 with the following should do the trick:

```
login_button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btn.btn-primary.pull-right")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `find_elements_by_xpath`:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\name\Downloads\q\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.plusportals.com/GuardianAngels")

login_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-primary pull-right']")
login_button[0].submit()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Added an answer. Let me know if it works for you. If it does please accept/check-mark the answer.

Comment: I know I'm late on seeing all of this information. My program that I am trying to make works now. honestly, I was not expecting any response so thank you

Answer (score 0):

To wait for an element and click after page load do the following.
Added login as well.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "UserName"))).send_keys("AAA")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "Password"))).send_keys("AAA")

login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.btn.btn-primary.pull-right")))
login_button.click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score -1):

#### In line 4 you are using:

```
login_button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btn btn-primary pull-right")
```

**There are multiple ways to do this:**

#### Method 1:

You can replace `driver.find_elements_by_class_name` to `driver.find_element_by_class_name`

```
login_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn btn-primary pull-right")
```

#### Method 2:

You have to put a [0] there because the click function does not take a list and to bypass that you would have to get the first item from the list and click it.

```
login_button[0].click() or login_button[0].submit()
```